# how to find the 'main' and 'secondary' diagonal positions given a random element

Tags: java, math, matrix

Problem:

> Given a matrix M of size NxN (square matrix), how can I find the 'main' and the 'secondary' diagonal of **any element** in it?

Example:

```
M = 

| A00 A01 A02 A03 A04 |

| A10 A11 A12 A13 A14 |

| A20 A21 A22 A23 A24 |

| A30 A31 A32 A33 A34 |

>>PICKED: A21

'Main' diag: A10, A21, A32

'Secondary' diag: A03, A12, A21, A31
```

**Context:**

I'm solving the **Eight Queen's** problem in Java. First of all, before making the Heuristics, i've done this methods:

`public boolean anyAtTheSameRow(Queen... queens)`

`public boolean anyAtTheSameCol(Queen... queens)`

```java
public boolean anyAtTheSameDiagonal(ChessBoard board, Queen... queens) {
        
        //How it will be done: (MY THOUGHTS)
        //1. Take the first queen. 
        //2. Get all of it's diagonal houses. "\"(main) diagonal and "/"(secondary) diagonal.
        //3. Check if the next queens current row and current col are inserted in any of these pos.
        //4. If any queen is inserted in the diagonal houses, then at least 1 queen can attack another. Will immediatly return true.
        //5. If, after all iterations, no queen was found at the queen[0] diagonal, then will return false. No attacks are possible.
```

And an important method, witch will get all of these together:

```
public boolean canAttackAny(ChessBoard board, Queen... queens) {
        return anyAtTheSameRow(queens) || anyAtTheSameCol(queens) || anyAtTheSameDiagonal(board, queens);
}
```

What i'm going to to is a loop, starting at the first row-col of the diagonal (variable starting point), then store the values of the next positions {x,y}, going up to down.

**What i've tried:**

For the main diagonal, i found this pattern for any element by a process of trial and error:

```
Starting point = 

{0, j-i} if i < j

{i-j, 0} if i > j

{0, 0} if i = j
```

But, for the secondary diagonal, i haven't found any patterns. I need help.

I hope my thoughts of solving part of the **Eight Queens** problem are also right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest the following pattern for the secondary diagonal:

```
Starting point = 

{i-j, 0} if (i + j) < N-1*

{N-1*, j-i} if (i + j) > N-1*

{N-1*, 0} if (i + j) = N-1*
```

*zero indexed so the right most column and bottom row are N-1

Looping is `i--` and `j++` with condition that i and j both remain in the range 0 to < N

Comment: Thank you! I'll try this later when I'm home. Helped a lot.